# All XP updates on DVD

Tags: windows-xp, updates

This is a general question for all XP systems. With the end of the XP life cycle, I began to wonder how people will get a system patched to the last update. I know about slipstreaming, but haven't really investigated it. I was wondering if there is a download site that has all the patches, updates and service packs for download. A bulk download that would contain everything with a front end that would query the system and install all the appropriate updates rather than the piecemeal setup that Microsoft uses. Since of course MS will not be providing this service. So a user could download the complete package to DVD and let it run on their system to provide all the updates etc. from DVD rather than the MS site.

Yes, I know the industry is moving on, but I have a number of people who refuse to relearn every change with each new OS. I have recommended that they move to Linux for this type of setup, but again they are resistant and want to keep the original GUI and feature set. I have for the most part with those that are willing to move to Win7 installed Classic shell and done other customizations, but there is a limit. A disk would make this so much easier.

Comment: While the question is generally interesting, PLEASE don't leave any Windows XP systems networked after XP reaches end-of-life. You must assume that, at end-of-life, all such machines are vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some people have put a lot of work into this; [this thread on something called the RyanVM forum](http://www.ryanvm.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7184) might be worth your while. (I haven't evaluated their work, but if that isn't a comprehensive package of updates between SP3 and current, then it's certainly a good start on one, and I'd expect an unofficial (or possibly even official) "Service Pack 4" to be available some time shortly after EOL in April.